# Is every symmetric graph a strongly regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a bit of a problem to develop an intuition about **symmetric graphs** (I only consider in the following connected simple graphs)... For example **cycles** (*but only up to 5 vertices*) and **complete graphs** are **symmetric** and **strongly regular**. But is every **symmetric graph** also **strongly regular**?

Counter-examples or some intuitive explanation is welcome. Complicated proofs
are maybe beyond what I can understand at the moment. Unfortunarely, also I am not very strong in group theory.

I know that every **symmetric graph** is **regular**.

Greets,
Lando

Comment: The answer is no. Counter-example would be the cycle on 6 vertices (if we exclude from the definition of strongly regular graphs the case were adjacent and non-adjacent vertices share 0 neighbours).

Answer (score 4):

[Wolfram’s article on symmetric graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricGraph.html) shows $4$ connected, symmetric, simple graphs on $6$ vertices; Wolfram’s article on strongly regular graphs shows only $3$ connected, strongly regular, simple graphs on $6$ vertices. Thus, there must be a symmetric graph that isn’t strongly regular. From the illustrations it appears that $C_6$ and $K_{3,3}$ are symmetric but not strongly regular, and the graph obtained from $C_6$ by adding the $3$ edges between diametrically opposite vertices is strongly regular but not symmetric.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your thoughts, I found out that I was wrong: Not all cycles are strongly regular. Only cycles up to 5 vertices are strongly regular. I edited this into my question above.

Comment: @user36124: You’re welcome!